# Index.php - Directory of Joomla 3 Templates

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, gavick

I'm using a GavickPro template... I would like to add some php code for making page class suffix working, but I don't know where is the index.php file where I have to write in...
Could you tell me the directory...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gavick use a framework for their template, the file you need to edit is different. The code you would normally find in the *index.php* is located in:

```
templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/layouts/default.php
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thx too much buddie

Comment: Forgot it, sorry xd